# Modifying coil spring to alter rate progressively

Tags: springs

I want to modify the coil springs in my car to lower it 1" without raising the spring rate, so simply trimming the overall length is not an option.  My idea is to remove material from along the top edge the active coils.  Obviously, making the rod diameter smaller will make it weaker so it will compress more under a given load.  This is where I will get my lowering.  I want a progressive rate, so I'm thinking I should remove material only from the first one or two coils.  In my head, this will yield a softer ride for normal driving on average highway irregularities when the spring is being compressed those first 2 inches or so.  Yet, it will be more resistant to the compression when under more load, such as on larger dips/humps and/or when the vehicle is loaded more.

So, if I were to remove material from the spring:

(1) Will the spring compress more and lower the car without increasing firmness?

(2) Will I actually get a progressive rate if I remove the material as described?

(3) What would be the difference between removing the material from, say, one coil versus spreading it along two or even three coils?  (The spring in question has 5 active coils)

Disclaimer:  I would remove material with a flap disc for better control and to minimize heat and to create a smooth surface to avoid stress risers.  I would also gradually taper in and out of the maximum amount removed from the coils instead of immediately digging in at the start and finish of the modified areas.

Comment: You probably both have to trim and remove material from the spring, because the first action will increase the spring constant, while the other action decreases it. How much of each will probably depend on the exact geometry of the spring.

Comment: I strongly recommend against removing material from the spring, because the spring was built from a carefully produced tempered material. You may well drastically affect its breaking / stress limit.   I strongly recommend purchasing other springs,  or better yet, taking a few minutes on this thing called "the Internet" to find out proper, safe, ways to lower the body.

Comment: I expect this will work out as successfully as using a bunch of screw hose clamps to bind adjacent coils together to lower the car.